# ControllerAdvice not catching exceptions as expected

Tags: java, spring, exception, model-view-controller

Given an exception thrown while processing a request handled by the Spring DispatcherServlet

Shouldn't this global handler be able to "catch" it ?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        error.setMessage("Please contact your administrator");
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Some tests I've carried out show that an handler like this is not able to catch exceptions thrown by formatters or even by the DispatcherServlet itself for example in the case it cannot find a suitable target handler.

Is this the expected behaviour ?
Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Are those exceptions thrown in controllers (or above)? Maybe they are thrown before calling controller.

Comment: Of  course they are...but I expect all of the exceptions raised while processing requests targeting the DispatcherServlet to be catched.